# Wilson Loop in AdS/CFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, ads-cft, wilson-loop

In AdS/CFT correspondence one can compare results in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM with string theory type IIB in $AdS_5 \times S^5$. One of the observables that it's possible to get non-perturbative results is the Wilson loop.

Maldacena proposed in [his paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9803002) that in the string side the expectation value of the Wilson loop is the area of the fundamental string that ends in the contour of the loop.

The metric of $AdS_5 \times S_5$ is given by:

> $dS^2 = \alpha' [ \frac{U^2}{R^2}(dt^2 + dx_i dx_i) + \frac{R^2}{U^2} dU^2 + d\Omega_5^2]$

From which one can obtain the induced metric on the worldsheet: $h_{\alpha \beta} = G_{MN} \frac{\partial X^M}{\partial X^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^N}{\partial X^{\beta}}$ and in the large N limit one gets the area as the nambu goto action:

> $S = \frac{1}{2\pi \alpha'} \int d\tau d\sigma \sqrt{det(h_{\alpha \beta})}$

Choosing a static gauge: $\tau = t$, $\sigma = x$, and fixing the coordinates in $S^5$ as constants $\theta^I_0$ one gets:

> $ S = \frac{T}{2\pi} \int dx \sqrt{U^4/R^4 + (\partial_x U)^2}$

From which we need to solve the Euler-Lagrange equations, in the paper Maldacena says that as the actions does not depend on X the canonical momentum is conserved, and one gets the condition:

> $\frac{U^4}{\sqrt{U^4/R^4 + (\partial_x U)^2)}} = constant$

But I can't exactly grasp what is he doing to get there, does anyone knows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just classical mechanics. We have a Lagrangian ${\cal L}(U,\partial_x U)$. Since the Lagrangian does not depend on time (here: $x$), the Hamiltonian 
$$
{\cal H} = \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_x U)} (\partial _x U) -{\cal L}
$$
is conserved. Presto.